# how to use a local archive as source code instead of git repo in Yocto?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to set a local archive as source code in the recipe to keep it private.

```
recipes-myproject
    ├── myproject
    │   └── myproject.zip
    └── myproject.bb
```

myproject.bb

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI = "file://myproject.zip"
S = "${WORKDIR}/myproject"
```

but I am getting the error `do_populate_lic: Fatal QA errors were found` and nothing under `tmp/work/cortexa57-cortexa53-poky-linux/myproject`.

it seems Yocto didn't unpack the zip at all, is it possible to use an archive as source code instead of Git repo?

Answer (score 0):

> do_populate_lic: Fatal QA errors were found

Try setting `LICENSE` variable withing your recipe, for example

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
```

> nothing under `tmp/work/cortexa57-cortexa53-poky-linux/myproject`

Maybe your recipe's `$WORKDIR` is under another subdirectory of `tmp/work`? Try running from initialized build environment

```
bitbake-getvar -r myproject WORKDIR
```

to find out work directory of your recipe.

> is it possible to use an archive as source code instead of Git repo?

I've verified this on Poky codename nanbield: it works fine there.

Comment: hello, thanks, but I don't want to disable the license QA process. The QA error is due to the license file not existing (the whole folder is empty), and I confirmed the work folder is correct.

Comment: You may verify if this works for you on latest Poky release with just this change. I suppose in your case you may have some additional configuration changes not mentioned in this question.